# Manipulate iFrame loaded with Ajax

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am working with a system that I have little control over. I would like to add some third-party javascript/jQuery (there is a mechanism to do this) to alter some hyperlinks within an iFrame.

The problem is, that the iFrame itself is brought in via AJAX. When I try to interact with it, jQuery cannot find it in the document. Here is some code I have attempted to use with no success:

```
$(document).on('click', '#cust_iframe_2', function(){
    alert('found');
});
```

The element is definitely there when I inspect the source. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When working with iFrames in jQuery, you've got to use the `.contents()` method.

[jQuery .contents() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

For example. if your "clickable" element in the iFrame is "#clickme", you'd do something like this:

```
var ifrStuff = $('#cust_iframe_2').contents().get(0);
$(ifrStuff).on('click','#clickme',function () {
    alert('found');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. So far I'm not having any luck with this suggestion within the confines of how I am able to add the javascript. I'll try to accomplish the same thing with a Chrome extension so I can see if I'm just limited by the web application itself.